# PHP Array echo 1 by 1

Tags: php, arrays

I am writting simple table output using PHP and the response of the API is Array.

```
Array
(
    [financial_entry] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [financial_date] => 31/01/2022 18:12:00
                    [account] => 333515              
                    [amount] => 100                                     
                    [reference] => 220131181159903
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [financial_date] => 31/01/2022 16:55:26
                    [account] => 333515              
                    [amount] => 100                                                
                    [reference] => 220131165525613
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [financial_date] => 31/01/2022 12:38:15
                    [account] => 333515    
                    [amount] => 100               
                    [reference] => 10031123815407
                )

        )

)
```

I want to create a table that I can echo the data one by one. My desired output is like this the screenshot ->https://prnt.sc/26nvu4m

I tried using the below code but error -

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'amount' in

```
foreach ($arrayfinancialentry1 as $result) {
                                             
echo "<tr>
    <td>{$result['reference']} </td>
    <td>{$result['financial_date']}</td>
    <td>{$result['account']}</td>
    <td>{$result['amount']}</td>
   </tr>";
}
```

Note: Sometimes the response of the Array is only because the data is empty.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 

)
```

Comment: `amount` is not an offset in the code provided. You could run a check on `$result` that is an array prior to the `echo`.

Comment: Try `$result['amount']`

Comment: With the update `$amount` is a variable because of the `$`. Remove that for it to be the static index.

Comment: Hi @user3783243, yeah,  I already edit the code but still errors show illegal string offset 'amount' in

Comment: Change `$result['$amount']` to `$result['amount']`

Comment: Yes @executable and Harshit, but still error shows -> https://prnt.sc/26nw1ff

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also include the error messages you are facing **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: The issue is when `[0] => ` or every time? It is very hard to tell which issue/error you have at this point, as question has had multiple updates to code. The error is the same? At error point what does `var_dump($result)` give

Comment: this is the var_dump($result) @user3783243 -> https://prnt.sc/26nw8ow

Comment: "Sometimes the response of the Array is only because the data is empty" - then why not check for these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Your $arrayfinancialentry1 is an array with a key [financial_entry] and this key has other arrays as value,
So when you do `$arrayfinancialentry1 as $result` you key [financial_entry] is now $result array which doesn't have columns your looking for but arrays inside it has those.So follow the below code.

```
if(!empty($arrayfinancialentry1)){
    foreach ($arrayfinancialentry1 as $key => $result) {
                                                 
            echo "<tr>
                <td>{$result['reference']} </td>
                <td>{$result['financial_date']}</td>
                <td>{$result['account']}</td>
                <td>{$result['amount']}</td>
            </tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: and add your echo inside `if(!empty($key){`

Comment: this is my code -> https://prnt.sc/26nw4mp

But this is the output that I am receiving.
-> https://prnt.sc/26nw60m

Nothings is showing in the table i created

Comment: If I used this code @Rao DYC -> https://prnt.sc/26nwaor

This errors shows -> https://prnt.sc/26nwavl

Comment: do `<td>$result['amount']</td>` without curly braces

Comment: If I remove the curly braces error show -> 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''

Here's the code -> https://prnt.sc/26nwetv

Comment: `<td>" .$result['amount'] ."</td>` do this I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I made some test if the key value exist using `isset`. If you wanted to create a table, you needed to use `<table></table>` tags.

```
<?php

$arrayfinancialentry1['financial_entry'][] = array('financial_date' => '31/01/2022 18:12:00', 'account' => '333515', 'amount' => '100', 'reference' => '220131181159903');
$arrayfinancialentry1['financial_entry'][] = array('financial_date' => '31/01/2022 16:55:26', 'account' => '333515', 'amount' => '100', 'reference' => '220131165525613');
$arrayfinancialentry1['financial_entry'][] = array('financial_date' => '31/01/2022 12:38:15', 'account' => '333515', 'amount' => '100', 'reference' => '10031123815407');
?>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    if (isset($arrayfinancialentry1['financial_entry'])) {
        foreach ($arrayfinancialentry1['financial_entry'] as $result) {

            echo "<tr>";
            if (isset($result['reference'])) {
                echo "<td>{$result['reference']} </td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td></td>";
            }

            if (isset($result['financial_date'])) {
                echo "<td>{$result['financial_date']} </td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td></td>";
            }

            if (isset($result['account'])) {
                echo "<td>{$result['account']} </td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td></td>";
            }
            if (isset($result['amount'])) {
                echo "<td>{$result['amount']} </td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td></td>";
            }

            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can run the code here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21f00292848b2e367ccf0113c76731d18e8f7f82

Comment: Hi @executable, this is not working on my end. Here's my code -> https://prnt.sc/26nwijz

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working ? The sample I gave you is ok, you can check the link. Can you `var_dump($arrayfinancialentry1);` . Why in the screen you have `$array` ?

Comment: here is the result of the var_dump($arrayfinancialentry1); -> https://prnt.sc/26nwmbr

Comment: And the output of `$array` ? Can you replace `$array` by `$arrayfinancialentry1` in your code

Comment: Yes @executable, your code is working!. my bad. Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score -3):

Try  code  like this  :

```
foreach ($Your_Main_Array as $sub_array){
    foreach ($sub_array as $result){
        echo $result['amount'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Code is text. There is no reason you cannot use copy and paste. Thanks.

Comment: I had to because I am using mobile phone to post the answer and there is no option to post code content via a mobile phone..

Comment: Of course there is. Markdown is markdown, no matter how to enter it. You just indent by 4 spaces as usual, or you can add 3 backticks on the previous line before the code starts, and 3 backticks on the line after the code finishes. Nothing in the mobile editor prevents you from doing that. I have posted code that way dozens of times. Please read [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to understand the formatting capabilities of the editor. It does not require you to use the helper buttons which you can see in the desktop version, if that's what you are thinking.

Comment: Finally @LaReyna. This is working. Thank you very much for posting.

Comment: Hi @LaReyna, your code is working but unfortunately if the Array is empty this is showing to the table -> https://prnt.sc/26nx3pa

Comment: @wrineswrines are you saying you don't want the table to be displayed when there are no entries in the array? If so then just count the number of items in the array before you echo any table markup

Comment: Please add the code in text form, and add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn fro mit